# ImportError on python 3, worked fine on python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, import, module

I'm getting an error when importing my `code_parsing` package with Python 3.2.

Directory `code_parsing` is within `PYTHONPATH` and contains the following files (some others too, but irrelvant here)

```
code_parsing/__init__.py
code_parsing/ada.py
```

`__init__.py` contains:

```
from ada import *
```

When importing my module I get this error:

```
>>> import code_parsing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "K:\CODE\pythonlib\code_parsing\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ada import *
ImportError: No module named ada
```

With python 2.7 on the same machine with the same environment it works fine.

Some precisions:

- Others import in the same directory using the same `directory/__init__.py` structure work fine.
- `ada.py` is a pure python file, no special compiled/cython/.pyd stuff.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python 3 uses *absolute imports*. Any unqualified name is imported as a *top-level module*.

You don't have a top-level `ada` module. You have a `code_parsing.ada` module instead so the following will work:

```
from code_parsing.ada import *
```

or use an explicit 'local package' reference:

```
from .ada import *
```

You can force the same behaviour in Python 2 with:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

See [PEP 328 – *Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for details.