# Subpackages and relative imports in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, python-2.x

I am using python 2:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.13 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

I have the following project structure:

```
.
└── foo
    ├── bar1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── mod1.py
    ├── bar2
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── mod2.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── start.py
```

start.py

```
from foo.bar2.mod2 import mod2_f
mod2_f()
```

mod1.py

```
def mod1_f():
    print "mod1_f"
```

mod2.py

```
from foo.bar1.mod1 import mod1_f

def mod2_f():
    mod1_f()
    print "mod2_f"
```

If I run start.py from an IDE things work ok.

However using something like this:

```
python ./foo/start.py
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./foo/start.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo.bar2.mod2 import mod2_f
ImportError: No module named foo.bar2.mod2
```

Now, let's say I change the imports to

start.py

```
from bar2.mod2 import mod2_f
mod2_f()
```

mod2.py

```
from bar1.mod1 import mod1_f

def mod2_f():
    mod1_f()
    print "mod2_f"
```

Now things work from the command line `python ./foo/start`
However, PyCharm complains. why these differences?

Comment: well, I am not using python 3. I am using python 2 at the moment

Comment: I'd say that's expected: it should be `from bar2.mod2 import mod2_f`

Comment: I tried that already and did not fix it..

Comment: please [edit] your question to show why this solution doesn't work, then. It _should_ work,given the clear project structure you provided. Of course, since you changed the names, a typo is always a possibility. But now that you know that it _should_ work, I'm sure you'll make it work.

Comment: and if it doesn't work, maybe it's because you're using python 3 whereas you think you're using python 2 :)

Comment: pycharm is probably configured to run on python 3. Check internal pycharm python engine. We already had problems like this with pycharm + python 2.7 installed independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` is the directory which contains everything, including `start.py`

So when from `start.py` you do this

```
from foo.bar2.mod2 import mod2_f
```

python looks for a `foo` module (`foo` *is* a module because it contains `__init__.py`), which too high in your directory structure. I suppose it works from the IDE because IDE adds every module directory to pythonpath. But not from command line it doesn't.

simple fix since `bar2` is a directory at the same level as `start.py`:

```
from bar2.mod2 import mod2_f
```

note that `from` works differently in python 3. See [ImportError on python 3, worked fine on python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564382/importerror-on-python-3-worked-fine-on-python-2-7), that's probably why PyCharm complains when fixing the import line. You should configure PyCharm so it uses Python 2 and not Python 3 for it to work, or just drop the `from` syntax altogether and do:

```
import bar2.mod2.mod2_f
```