# Why I can't move import at top?

Tags: python, flask

I am learning Flask. I found example with follow code

`__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

`view.py`:

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "hello world"
```

and `run.py` (on top level):

```
from app import app
app.run()
```

I can't understand why I can't move `from app import views` to the top. If I do so I am getting error:

```
> run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\app1\run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "F:\app1\app\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import views
  File "F:\app1\app\views.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
```

Comment: I think this is a relative import vs absolute import problem in python 3.

Comment: check this Q&A and tell me if it solves it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564382/importerror-on-python-3-worked-fine-on-python-2-7

Comment: I believe this is a circular-import problem: `app` object has to be defined in `__init__.py` before it can be imported from `view.py`.

Answer (score 0):

In `run.py` file line

```
from app import app
```

means "from package app (folder with `__init__.py` file, F:\app1\app in your case, import object app", and in `__init__.py` file line

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

creates an [application object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#application-object). Main confusion caused by your application name - `app` - which coincides with application object name.
If you move line

```
from app import views
```

above

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

`from app import app` in `view.py` will raise `ImportError`, because object `app` from `app` package not defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

Python is interpreted language. When it comes to one line it try to execute it. And that is why you cannot import `views` before defining app.

Working version of `__init__.py`

```
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views # it will "execute: views.py"
# views.py - indenting for better understanding
    from app import app # App is defined here and it can be imported
```

Not working version of `__init__.py`

```
from app import vies # it will execute vies.py"
# vies.py - indenting for better understanding
    from app import app # Exception - app doesn't exist here
app = Flask(__name__)
```

You need to be really careful with python imports.